# Clock loop numbers in canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Good evening.

Who can explain why, after canvas.translate(0, -canvasRadius * 0.8); we need to use
canvas.rotate(-ang)?

I assume this is to "return" to the original 0 position. But it is not clear what the lines after it are for.

```
for (num = 1; num < 13; num++) {
    ang = (num * Math.PI) / 6;
    canvas.rotate(ang);
    canvas.translate(0, -canvasRadius * 0.8);
    canvas.rotate(-ang);
    canvas.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    canvas.rotate(ang);
    canvas.translate(0, canvasRadius * 0.8);
    canvas.rotate(-ang);
  }
```

Comment: Notice also the `canvas.rotate(ang);` before `canvas.translate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it rotates canvas so that the subsequent translate is at the correct point for the number. A rotation in the opposite direction makes sure that the subsequent `fillText` is the right way up.

The remaining rotations and translate reverse the previous operations and relocate back to the origin ready for the next iteration.